# Annotating a generic class as a JSF managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, generics

I came across code of the following type:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
SomeClass<T> {
    ... blah-blah
}
```

Since the framework instantiates this as a generic **SomeClass** object with no type information, do you see any benefits from such code? Or would you classify it as a code smell?

Comment: Where did you come across this?

Comment: the code was authored in NetBeans for a past project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generics are compiletime syntactic sugar (and thus totally absent during runtime). JSF instantiates beans during runtime (by reflection means). So, yes this is definitely code smell. It would only make sense if `SomeClass` is a base class which managed beans extend from (but is by itself not a managed bean at all).

E.g.

```
public abstract class CrudBean<T extends SomeBaseEntity> {
    private List<T> entities;
    // ...
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
public class ProductsBean extends CrudBean<Product> {
    // ...
}
```